# window.print needs location.reload to make screen return to normal

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a print option where when a user clicks on button a specific `div` gets printed. Here is the code:

```
function printDiv(divName) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
        window.print();
        window.close();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;

        /*location.reload();*/
    }

<button id="print-canvas-button" class="aui-button" style ="float: right" onclick="printDiv('productCanvas')" style="float: right">Print Canvas</button>
```

Problem: When I click on this button for print, it works but needs a reload to come back to normal, or else no functionality works on screen. How can I fix this without `location.reload`?

Comment: Stop messing around with the page content with JS - and instead use a print stylesheet that only shows the element you want to print, and removes everything else.

Comment: That's what I am doing passing the div and it prints well but needs reload every time.

Comment: No, it's not what you are doing - you are messing with the document content via JS, and that's why you have this problem.

Comment: Ok I got it, but if I do not manipulate the div  it prints the whole page. In the stylesheet I already have removed the header and foot but there are other elements as well.

Comment: And what is stopping you from removing the rest as well?

Comment: That's the problem , the div I want is inside the iframe and  there are other links outside of Iframe which does not work when when I try to ignore that.

Comment: I got the problem, actually I am using an iframe where if I just use window.print it will always print the whole page. Which ofcourse I would not need. So the right way would be to manipulate it with javascript but unable to avoid the page refresh.

Comment: Just because it is in an iframe doesn't mean you can not use a print stylesheet. (Unless you have no access to the iframe content, because it is from a different domain - but then JS won't help you either, because of SOP.)

Comment: So can you suggest any alternative for that or any change in the code

Comment: Not until you provide a [mcve] and a clear description of what exactly you want to achieve. Please edit the question in that regard.

Comment: Start off by removing the `window.close`. Actually I'd recommend creating a new window for this with `window.open` instead of half-destroying your current window and then trying to restore it.